# Save cookie login for Webview in another activity

Tags: android, cookies, webview

I have a webview if user not login it always return login page.
In activity A I have a webview with content is login form, after login success webview will show `MyPage` web, in `MyPage` I have a link `TagertBlank` have properties `target="_blank"` so  when click link `TargetBlank` I need open activity B have webview to load `TargetBlank` link. I need save cookie login from Webview in activity A to set cookie in Webview activity B, so when Webview in A call `onPageFinished` I get cookie and save to shared preferences with code

```js
String cookies = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url);
SharedPrefs.getInstance().put(SharedPrefsKey.KEY_COOKIE_WEB_VIEW, cookies);
```

and in Activity B I set cookie for webview with code:

```js
String cookies = SharedPrefs.getInstance().get(SharedPrefsKey.KEY_COOKIE_WEB_VIEW, String.class);
            String[] splitCookies = cookies.split(";");
            CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                for (String cookie : splitCookies) {
                    cookieManager.setCookie(urlLoadWebView, cookie.trim());
                }
                cookieManager.flush();
                cookieManager.setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(mWebView, true);
            } else {
                CookieSyncManager.createInstance(mWebView.getContext());
                cookieManager.removeSessionCookie();
                for (String cookie : splitCookies) {
                    cookieManager.setCookie(urlLoadWebView, cookie.trim());
                }
                CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync();
            }
            mWebView.loadUrl(urlLoadWebView);
```

but webview in B always turn out to login page so I log cookie in activity B and see it not sample cookie when login in A.
How I can save and set cookie login for webview in B?